# Whats wrong with my lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I want to get string of checkedListbox selected values like 1,3,4. To achieve this i have written a lambda expression:

```
private string GetCheckedIDs(CheckBoxList chkLst)
{
    string chkedVal = string.Empty;
    ((List<string>)chkLst.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(s => s.Selected).Select(s => s.Value))
                                                                         .ForEach(item => chkedVal = item + ",");
   return chkedVal.Remove(chkedVal.LastIndexOf(","));
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.
```

Comment: @drachenstern: I rolled back the edit because the error message actually contains the words "Unable to cast object of type".  Your edit made it seem like that was commentary from Ulhas.  If you care about the rest of the edit, you can make it again, but make sure the complete error message remains intact.

Comment: @drachenstern: Looks good now :)  If you feel you want to change the rest again, I won't roll that back.  I only cared about the error message remaining intact.

Comment: @Merlyn I was only trying to format that initially, the two code blocks. I think I actually merge-collided with you the first time, and didn't want to keep colliding, so left it alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your lambda expression - the problem is the casting from `IEnumerable<String>` to `List<String>` You can't cast to a list, but this should work:

```
chkLst.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
      .Where(s => s.Selected)
      .Select(s => s.Value).ToList()
      .ForEach(item =>   chkedVal = item + ",");
```

Here is a better option, using [`String.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx). It still selects the strings, but avoids string concatenation (and the last comma!):

```
string chkedVal = String.Join(",", chkLst.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                                    .Where(s => s.Selected).Select(s => s.Value))
```

Or on .Net 3.5 you don't have that handy overload - you need to create an array for [`String.Join(String, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
string chkedVal = String.Join(",", chkLst.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                                     .Where(s => s.Selected)
                                     .Select(s => s.Value).ToArray())
```

Comment: thanks chkLst.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(s => s.Selected).ToList().ForEach(item => chkedVal = item.Value + ",");

Comment: @Gabe - Thanks for the links. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

The code may compile, but you'll get that error at run time.  This is because the `IEnumerable<string>` returned by Linq isn't actually a list.  This is for performance reasons, otherwise Linq would have to build the whole list up front, instead of building each item as it is needed.

There is a Linq method on `IEnumerable<T>` to force Linq to build the list up front, though  - `ToList`:

```
chkLst.Items
    .OfType<ListItem>()
    .Where(s => s.Selected)
    .Select(s => s.Value)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item => chkedVal = item + ",");
```